# How to know gmail, which user use for in app billing?

Tags: android, gmail, in-app-billing, multiple-accounts

I want to add in app billing to my android app. But I face a problem. If user logins 2 gmails on device (gmail A and gmail B), how can I know which of them is used for in app billing? We know that, at the moment of paying, user can pick any of his gmails to continue buying items. And json data from Google doesn't includes information about chosen gmail. Can any body help me? Thank a lot.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't find out what the google account is. Maybe if you explained what you need it for, there might be a better solution

Comment: Hi Mircea Nistor. This is my problem. User with gmail A bought an item. If user runs app without Internet, I want to load that item for user. We have no internet connection for checking information, so we have to use local data to verify that: this user bought this item or not.